# Exporting HTML table data to a new sheet into the existing work book if exists else update that existing sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to export HTML table data to existing workbook as a new sheet. If particular sheet exists with the name then update that one only. using JS or Jquery or angularJS

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can do something like this

```js
var cssLink = $('link[href*="light.css"]');
// we check if light css exist
if ($(cssLink).length) {
  cssLink.replaceWith('<link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/darkly/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/darkly/4/darkly/bootstrap.css">
<link href="light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<header class="bg-dark text-light pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Demo Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="carbon-block"></div>
</header>
```